# Problem mount error 13 trying to mount NAS share

Tags: 11.04, mount, share

I am trying to mount a NAS share to my Ubuntu 11.04. This is my first ever Linux machine, so everything is totaly new for me.

I can access the shares from my windows at: \192.168.0.9\Packages (Packages is the share name on the NAS machine)

I can also mount (or at least I see the Packages icon on the desktop while going through Places) to the Packages share.

However, I want to mount Packages to my \home\administrator\Packages and here is the problem

Trying the following command:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.9/Packages/ \home\administrator\Packages
```

throws error: mount error(13) permission denied.

I am putting in my password for the administrator when prompted.  (no note - I have likewise to add the Ubuntu to the AD)

I than tried to add the -o username:administrator,password:password   but got the same error.

I have isntalled smbfs lready, but don't think that this is the problem

```
sudo apt-get install smbfs
```

I will appreciate any help

I also tried

```
mount.cifs //192.168.0.9/Packages /home/administrator/Packages -o dom=domain,user=administrator,pass=password
```

This gives

```
mount error(1): Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EUREKA !!!

Because my NAS is a Netgear reaadynas 1100, it's running it's own CIFS unix system. The username and password I had to use are NOT of the domain, but actually of the NAS system.

So I changed to the NAS admin user + password and all is working !!

Answer (score 1):

The last command you ran needs sudo

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.9/Packages /home/administrator/Packages -o dom=domain,user=administrator,pass=password
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found when getting my Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 to mount my WDTVLiveHub share for my CouchPotato server. After giving up on Google and telling myself to RTFM I realised that I needed to include the sec=ntlm switch to avoid the Permission Denied error:

Add this to the /etc/fstab entry:

```
//host_name/WDTVLiveHub /media/WDTVLiveHub cifs username=Guest,password=Guest,sec=ntlm,nounix,uid=couchpotato,gid=couchpotato,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Then mount in the usual way:

```
sudo mount -a
```